# Add button to Unity View

Tags: c#, android, eclipse, unity-game-engine, android-xml

I am trying to add a button to my Unity View in Eclipse. I have imported the Unity project and I have changed the onCreate method so that my setContentView is setting my own xml layout as opposed to the Unity View. Then I add the Unity view to this layout. This works  but instead of the button sitting on top of my Unity View it is at the side of my screen. Please see my code below. This is my onCreate method:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().takeSurface(null);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getBoolean("hide_status_bar", true))
            getWindow()
                    .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Character_Mesh", "LoadScene", "CM_Unity_Elf");

        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();

        detector = new GestureDetector(this, this);
        detector.setOnDoubleTapListener(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.menu_buttons);

        LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlContainer);

        lLayout.addView(playerView);

        playerView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        playerView.requestFocus();
    }
```

This is my xml layout menu_buttons:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rlContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_call" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way that I can add a button on top of the Unity View instead of to the side of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to do this myself. Instead of add the Unity View to your own layout you can inflate your own RelativeLayout and add this to the Unity View and then set the Unity View as the setContentView.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.menu_buttons, null);



        mUnityPlayer.addView(layout);
        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        setContentView(playerView);
```

To set up OnTouchListener for the Unity View you use:

```
playerView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this - I was able to get what you described to work, however how did you get your menu buttons to receive touch events? From what I am seeing Unity is a Native App so its using the native touch events and ignoring my on touch event calls in the java code

Thanks!

Comment: I used OnTouchListener. You just have to make sure that you set the OnTouchlistener for the UnityView. I will edit my code above and show you how I didi it.

Comment: hmm, doesn't seem to do the trick - (setOnTouchListenertakes a setOnTouchListener not this)

RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout, null);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300,100));
layout.addView(b);
mUnityPlayer.addView(layout);
View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
setContentView(playerView);
        
playerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HI", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
   }
  });

Comment: I made a stack overflow question regarding this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239692/native-android-activity-and-with-touchevents-in-java-required-using-unity3d

Comment: FYI - the issue was that Unity now requires a metadata item to be added   <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />