# Native Android Activity and with touchevents in Java required using Unity3D

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-ndk, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and exporting the Unity Project as an eclipse project

this results in a simple NativeApplication

```
public class UnityPlayerNativeActivity extends NativeActivity
{
    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;    
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().takeSurface(null);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
            getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

    Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello From Java", ).show();                }   });

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.layout, null);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(300,30));
        layout.addView(b);

        mUnityPlayer.addView(layout);
        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        setContentView(playerView);
```

As you can see I have added a relativeLayout that I am inflating on top of the unity layout.

However since Unity resides in Native Code and the class is a NativeActivity
The touch events for my button will not work in Java - 
Since Unity compiles to a DLL I do not have access to the native code to send (through JNI) touch events back to Java

Is there another way to do this?
How can I get touch events to be fired in Java? Or how can I write an extension of the Native Activity that can capture the touch events in the NDK so I can pass them up to java?

What I find interesting is that If I do not use the unity view, and just setcontentview to my own layout - the touch events do work on java side
but the second I use the unity view I no longer can use the touch events in java

Answer (score 0):

What I had works fine the issue is that android requires a meta-data to be added to the xml manifest to tell unity to pass events to dalvik

see UnityPlayerNativeActivity
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html